# Passing Current Polymer Object (this) into a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, polymer

What's the best way to pass the current object to a callback function?

I have been using something like:

```
var that = this;
```

For example:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="stackx-example">
    <template>
        <div id="container">{{innards}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('stackx-example', {
            ready: function() {
                var jax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                jax.open('GET', '/jaxson/testing/', true);
                jax.send();
                var that = this;
                jax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (jax.readyState == 4 && jax.status == 200) {
                    that.innards = jax.responseText;
                }
            }
            },
            innards: '..missing'
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: i have been doing the same thing. IDK if it is considered correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` value within the callback to the same `this` value used outside the callback:

```
jax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (jax.readyState == 4 && jax.status == 200) {
    this.innards = jax.responseText;
  }
}.bind(this);
```

As a bit of a tangent, this is a great opportunity to use [`<core-ajax>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax) instead of a plain `XMLHttpRequest`. It will lead to more idiomatic Polymer code:

```
<polymer-element name="stackx-example">
  <template>
      <div id="container">{{innards}}</div>

      <core-ajax auto
                 url="/jaxson/testing/"
                 handleAs="text"
                 response="{{innards}}">
      </core-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
      Polymer({
        innards: '..missing'
      });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I will start using `.bind` since that'll clear some of the code up. I'm using _core-ajax_ for other things (so **nice and simple!**), but it wasn't json encoding an object with multiple levels, so the jax  function happened.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube-video-wall/blob/master/google-youtube-video-wall.html#L524 might be relevant to your situation—it's an example of using `JSON.stringify()` to produce the input string to `<core-ajax>`. You'd need to adapt it a bit to deal with nested objects, but the general approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another Alternative (ES6), works for me without bind()

```
jax.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
    if (jax.readyState == 4 && jax.status == 200) {
    this.innards = jax.responseText;
    }};
```